# Retrieving top three brands with highest sales for each year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Let's say I have a table that provides sales data of alcoholic beverage brands.

| Year | Quarter | Type | Brand | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | Beer | Brand A | 10.5 |
| 2020 | 1 | Beer | Brand B | 5.1 |
| 2020 | 1 | Beer | Brand C | 8.2 |
| 2020 | 1 | Beer | Brand D | 7.7 |
| 2020 | 2 | Beer | Brand A | 12.5 |
| 2020 | 2 | Beer | Brand B | 6.1 |
| 2020 | 2 | Beer | Brand C | 8.2 |
| 2020 | 2 | Beer | Brand D | 7.8 |
| 2020 | 3 | Beer | Brand A | 8.5 |
| 2020 | 3 | Beer | Brand B | 7.1 |
| 2020 | 3 | Beer | Brand C | 8.2 |
| 2020 | 3 | Beer | Brand D | 7.4 |
| 2020 | 4 | Beer | Brand A | 2.5 |
| 2020 | 4 | Beer | Brand B | 8.1 |
| 2020 | 4 | Beer | Brand C | 8.2 |
| 2020 | 4 | Beer | Brand D | 7.7 |

With this table, I would like to rank the brands based on their yearly sales.

| Year | Type | Brand | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Beer | Brand A | 34.0 |
| 2020 | Beer | Brand C | 32.8 |
| 2020 | Beer | Brand D | 30.6 |
| 2020 | Beer | Brand B | 26.4 |

The next step would be to retrieve the data per quarter based on this ranking, but ommitting anything outside of the established annual top 3. So I would only like brand A, C and D to show up in the table in a descending order based on the sales value in their respective quarters, and for brand B to never show up. Like this:

| Year | Quarter | Type | Brand | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | Beer | Brand A | 10.5 |
| 2020 | 1 | Beer | Brand C | 8.2 |
| 2020 | 1 | Beer | Brand D | 7.7 |
| 2020 | 2 | Beer | Brand A | 12.5 |
| 2020 | 2 | Beer | Brand C | 8.2 |
| 2020 | 2 | Beer | Brand D | 7.8 |
| 2020 | 3 | Beer | Brand A | 8.5 |
| 2020 | 3 | Beer | Brand C | 8.2 |
| 2020 | 3 | Beer | Brand D | 7.4 |
| 2020 | 4 | Beer | Brand C | 8.2 |
| 2020 | 4 | Beer | Brand D | 7.7 |
| 2020 | 4 | Beer | Brand A | 2.5 |

I have been trying to query this with SQL, however, I'm facing challenges with aggregating the data first to establish a top 3 and then for that top 3 to be disaggregated in each quarter separately. Is there a way to make this work with SQL? I would need to do this with many types of products, so simply querying for brand names would not be preferable.

I can create an aggregate top 3 based on the values in the table, however, the last step to disaggregate the data based on the top 3 that I established in the second table is something I have not been able to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

One approach, using `RANK()` to find the top 3 performing brands per year:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Year, Brand
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Year, Brand
    QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER SUM(Sales) DESC) <= 3
)

SELECT t1.Year, t1.Quarter, t1.Type, t1.Brand, t1.Sales
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.Year = t1.Year AND t2.Brand = t1.Brand
ORDER BY t1.Year, t1.Quarter, t1.Sales DESC;
```